# Javascript: keypress/keycode

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using Javascript [beginner only] for computing the "Remaining Spots" of a Spots.

SAMPLE GUI:

[image]

Scenario:

I input `22 spots` then for the `txtA I input 1` after that I click outside of the txtA the `Remaining Spots is already "22" [it should be "21"`]. But when I tried to `change the value of txtA to "2"` the remaining spots now is already `"21" [it should be "20"]`
.

Code for my ASP.NET

```
protected void txtA_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  txtRemaining.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtSlot.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(txtA.Text)).ToString();
}

protected void txtSlot_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int slot= Convert.ToInt32(txtSlot.Text);
  txtRemaining.Text = Convert.ToString(slot);
}
```

Javascript:

```
function checkIt(evt) {
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode

if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
  return false
}
status = ""
var comp1= document.getElementById("<%= __txt67Value1.ClientID %>").value;
var comp2 =  document.getElementById("<%= txtSlot.ClientID %>").value;
document.getElementById("<%= txtRemaining.ClientID %>").value = comp2- comp1;
return true
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How you trigger the `checkIt` ? - The title is more than a series of keywords, please make it a little better... and debug your code with your browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kwPy4/

```
var $comp1 = document.getElementById("<%= __txt67Value1.ClientID %>");
var $comp2 = document.getElementById("<%= txtSlot.ClientID %>");

function CheckIt() {
    var resultSlot = $comp2.val() - $comp1.val();
    $comp1.val(resultSlot);
}

$(document).on("blur", "<%= __txt67Value1.ClientID %>", function () {
    CheckIt();
});
```